# How to store NSMutableIndexSet in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, nsuserdefaults

Currently I'm saving bookmarks in `NSMutableIndexSet`

```
- (BOOL)saveBookmark
{
if (!bookmarkIndex) {
    bookmarkIndex = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
}
if (currentIndex) {
    [bookmarkIndex addIndex:currentIndex];
    return [bookmarkIndex containsIndex:currentIndex];
}
return NO;
}
```

But when I exit the app and come back to check on bookmarks, the bookmarks are not showing then.

So thinking of storing bookmarks in `NSUserDefaults`.

Is it possible to store `NSMutableIndexSet` in `NSUserDefaults` or only `NSMutableArray` can be saved in `NSUserDefaults`.

Is there is any example of storing `NSMutableIndexSet` in `NSUserDefaults`?

Appreciate help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `NSUserDefaults` all you can store are **property lists**. Read more about them here:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303

As you can see, you cannot store a `NSIndexSet` in a **property list**, so you will need to use either a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`. I do not see any reason why cannot you store an array.

See the answer below on how to get indexes into an array:

- [How to get indexes from NSIndexset into an NSArray in cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773180/how-to-get-indexes-from-nsindexset-into-an-nsarray-in-cocoa)

Comment: I think this helps me. Let me try. Thanks for help.