# Create NSIndexSet from integer array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, nsarray, nsindexset

I converted an NSIndexSet to an [Int] array using the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28964059/6481734 I need to do essentially the opposite, turning the same kind of array back into an NSIndexSet.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

## Swift 3

[`IndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexset) can be created directly from an array literal using [`init(arrayLiteral:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexset/1779813-init), like so:

```
let indices: IndexSet = [1, 2, 3]
```

## Original answer (Swift 2.2)

Similar to [pbasdf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977993/3141234), but uses [`forEach(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689783-foreach)

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10]

let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
array.forEach(indexSet.add) //Swift 3
//Swift 2.2: array.forEach{indexSet.addIndex($0)}

print(indexSet)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use to reloadTableSection is it work to one section?

Comment: @BrunoFernandes Uh... What?

Answer (score 79):

This will be a lot easier in Swift 3:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10]
let indexSet = IndexSet(array)
```

Wow!

Comment: Even better, it can be assigned from an Integer Literal. See my answer

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Excellent, that _is_ even better.

Comment: It is very annoying this can't be seen by typing IndexSet.init and using an autocomplete option.

Answer (score 28):

**Swift 3+**

```
let fromRange = IndexSet(0...10)
let fromArray = IndexSet([1, 2, 3, 5, 8])
```

Added this answer because the `fromRange` option wasn't mentioned yet.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4.2**

From existing array:

```
let arr = [1, 3, 8]
let indexSet = IndexSet(arr)
```

From array literal:

```
let indexSet: IndexSet = [1, 3, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `NSMutableIndexSet` and its `addIndex` method:

```
let array : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10]
print(array)
let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
for index in array {
    indexSet.addIndex(index)
}
print(indexSet)
```